# Store an undefined amount of integers

Tags: java, arrays, variables, primes

My assignment is to check if a number is a prime number, or if it , then display what it divides by ( for example 12 divides by 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 12.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class kt_4_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[num];
        for (int count; count <= num; count++) {
            if (num % count == 0) {
                // need to store the numbers somehow, possibly in an array.
            }
            // Or, if the amount of numbers it can be divided by
                    //is 2 ( meaning 1 and itself ), then say the number is a prime.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: use a Set to store factors. check my answer please.

Comment: as I said, the actual problem is that I don´t know how to store the numbers, also, I have to get the number of stored numbers for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of storing an undefined amount of numbers is with an ArrayList. An ArrayList is just a dynamic list that grows and shrinks to meet the need of the programmer.

```
ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
```

[Java Documentation ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lists. Or you can print them in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a data structure of variable size, which can be extended. I would suggest, you use Vector class defined in java.util package.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html